# Rails : Ruby Gem Local version works, but github version does not work, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to use one ruby gem named **wikimeta** in my rails project. I put the following line in my Gemfile :

```
gem 'wikimeta', :git => 'git@github.com:quandl/wikimeta.git'
```

and did bundle install. Then, I tried to instantiate a new object of class **Import** which is a class from the **wikimeta** gem. But, it shows me the following error when I try to run a test script (test.rb file) including the Import class.

```
test.rb:13:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Importer (NameError)
```

But, when I change the **wikimeta** gem reference to my local copy in my Gemfile like this :

```
gem 'wikimeta', :path => "../wikimeta"
```

Then the test script works perfectly. I have the exact same version of **wikimeta** on github. But, why it is not working when I refer to the github version? Could anyone please point out ?

**EDIT** : test.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'wikimeta'
require 'pipeline'

include Wikimeta

import_spec = ImportSpec.new()

importer = Importer.new({
                            :token => '9oTxpMsR7b',
                            :environment => 'production',
                            :verbose => true,
                            :mode => 'review'
                        })
```

To mention here: **ImportSpec** class is from pipeline gem which works fine. **Importer** class is from wikimeta gem which is not working. When I run the following command :

```
bundle exec ruby test.rb
```

It gives me error :

```
test.rb:13:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Importer (NameError)
```

both pipeline and wikimeta are from same place. My Gemfile looks like this :

```
gem 'pipeline', :git => 'git@github.com:quandl/pipeline.git'
gem 'wikimeta', :git => 'git@github.com:quandl/wikimeta.git'
```

It's weird that one gem is working but the other is not.

Comment: Please show us your `test.rb` script.

Comment: Please look at my EDIT. I really appreciate your time and help. And, please let me know if you need more info. I am stuck with this for couple of days :( I really need help.

Comment: Hi @RyanBigg , could you please look at my edit ? what do you think ?

Comment: Hi @RyanBigg, could you find any clue of what's going on here ? Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like that repository exists at that URL. I don't see the repository on the github page and I get the following error when trying to install the gem with bundler:

```
Fetching git@github.com:quandl/wikimeta.git
ERROR: Repository not found.
```

Where did you download the local gem from?

Comment: oh, it's a private repo that is why you can't pull it :( sorry about this.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and trial, one thing worked for me at last. 
I had to specify the branch of my github repo of my wikimeta gem in my Gemfile.

```
gem 'gem_name', :git => 'git@github.com:user_name/gem_name.git' , :branch => 'develop'
```

Then, it started working perfectly.

Comment: It would typically clone from the master branch, which is why it wasn't working.